# Swift 2.0 Type of expression is ambiguous without more context `.FlexibleHeight`

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Using XCode 7.1, OS X 10.10.5

I'm implementing ENSideMenu library, and am running into this error with two methods in the library:

```
    if (NSClassFromString("UIVisualEffectView") != nil) {
        // Add blur view
        var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
        visualEffectView.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
        visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth // error points to .FlexibleHeight
        sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    }
    else {
        // TODO: add blur for ios 7
    }
}

public convenience init(sourceView: UIView, menuViewController: UIViewController, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition) {
    self.init(sourceView: sourceView, menuPosition: menuPosition)
    self.menuViewController = menuViewController
    self.menuViewController.view.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
    self.menuViewController.view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth // error points to .FlexibleHeight
    sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(self.menuViewController.view)
}
```

Both point to `.FlexibleHeight`.. What is the problem here? Thanks

Comment: See my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets

Comment: @matt Thanks for the link - I'll be reading up some more on Set's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
```

Comment: is that equivalent to .FlexibleHeight.union(.FlexibleWidth)?

Comment: Perhaps the point is why were there down votes on the answer by @LokeshDudhat.

Comment: @zaph But that has nothing to do with me; he should comment on his own answer, not on mine.

Comment: @nielsbot Yes, but the latter is sort of overkill. What if you had four of these? Better to chain three union operations or just make a nice set literal? Now, of course, if you are forming your set dynamically, it's another story.

Comment: @matt Yes, just answering your question. It is just a shame that down voters have such for trouble commenting and are asked not to.

Comment: Both answers were right however this one is more succinct, hence my upvote. I don't think that Lokesh should have been downvoted however. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Actually, I just didn't know you could specify it like that. Just reading the Swift library definitions of what to do with options bits doesn't lead you to the array notation. :)

Comment: @nielsbot Actually, yes it does. This is an OptionSetType, which adopts SetAlgebraType, which adopts ArrayLiteralConvertible.

Comment: maybe it leads *you* to that conclusion, but I missed it

Comment: (that was supposed to have a smiley)

Answer (score 6):

Use below code: there some change in swift 2.0 - .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth to [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]

```
 if (NSClassFromString("UIVisualEffectView") != nil) {
        // Add blur view
        var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
        visualEffectView.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
        visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth] // error points to .FlexibleHeight
        sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    }
    else {
        // TODO: add blur for ios 7
    }


public convenience init(sourceView: UIView, menuViewController: UIViewController, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition) {
    self.init(sourceView: sourceView, menuPosition: menuPosition)
    self.menuViewController = menuViewController
    self.menuViewController.view.frame = sideMenuContainerView.bounds
    self.menuViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight , .FlexibleWidth] // error points to .FlexibleHeight
    sideMenuContainerView.addSubview(self.menuViewController.view)
}
```

Comment: Two down, one up: Iteresting.